# ERROR: syntax error at or near ";" Position: 102

Tags: mysql, sql

As a student in SQL, I'm trying to execute this command :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student
WHERE name = 'Evan' AND (lastName = 'Bhops' OR lastName = 'Hops');
```

But I'm getting this error :

> ERROR: syntax error at or near ";" Position: 102

I'm using mySql Command line

I'm a beginner and I would love to understand why?

Comment: Which database are you using?  How are you executing the query?

Comment: I can't seem to see anything wrong with it!

Comment: Maybe whatever "flavor" of actual SQL database system you're using doesn't like the semicolon after the command ..... that's what the error message seems to suggest......

Comment: You had a closing parenthesis before, but now you don't. If your current query is the one you are using, then put back that parenthesis

Comment: @marc_s It's super weird but my teacher told us to always put a semicolon at the end of every statement , but in my SQL editor when I remove the semicolon the command execute properly  . Thank you for help !

Comment: @BobSinclaire -- your sql editor is probably set to use a different delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the semicolon seems obvious.  I would also suggest using `in`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student
WHERE name = 'Evan' AND lastName IN ('Bhops' , 'Hops')
```

Comment: It worked but I would love to understand why? Usually a semicolon is a must at the end of every statement . But why sometimes I must not add semicolon?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon and put a closing parenthesis:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student
WHERE name = 'Evan' AND (lastName = 'Bhops' OR lastName = 'Hops')
```